# crop a DEM and keep proper referencing

Tags: matlab, mapping, geospatial

I've downloaded the GMTED2010 digital elevation model (DEM) from [the USGS](http://eros.usgs.gov/#/Find_Data/Products_and_Data_Available/GMTED2010), tiles N30W120_150 and N30W150_150.  It's a 500 m DEM. I would like to join these into on file in matlab so I tried:

```
Z=[Z150 Z120]; %Join the dems at their matching side
R=R120; %Create a new spatial referencing object based on the old one.
R.Lonlim=[R150.Lonlim(1),R120.Lonlim(2)]; %Modify what changed in R
R.RasterSize=size(Z); %Adjust the RasterSize referenced in R.
```

This works, but about 1/3 is pacific ocean which I'd like to remove for size/computation sake. Importantly, though, would be to keep the referencing information correct in R.

```
%Crop DEM to remove most ocean pixels.  about a 1/3 of dem.
Z=Z(:,floor(20/0.0042):end); %crop Z from -90 to -130 (20 degrees from the start (-150) longitude at 0.0042 deg/pixel according to the referencing info
R.Lonlim=[-150.0001+floor(20/0.0042)*0.0042, -90.0001]; %substract number of pixels cropped times deg/pixel value
R.RasterSize=size(Z); %Adjust the RasterSize referenced in R.
```

The problem is when I try to look at the elevation at a specific location such as:

```
lat=[39 38 47.22];
lat=dms2degrees(lat);
long=[-105 52 9.84];
long=dms2degrees(long);

hght=ltln2val(Z,R,lat,long);
```

the value given by hght isn't correct.  In fact, if I look at a subset around the lat,long:

```
[r c]=latlon2pix(R,lat,long);
Z(r-30:r+3,c-30:c+30)
```

The value in `hght` isn't even in this centered subset. I'd understand if I was 1 pixel off or so, but why am I so far off? Using `hght=ltln2val(Z,R,lat,long)` WITHOUT cropping but still combined gives the correct (same value as with just the Z120 DEM) value so I assume my referencing object is wrong.

Any help someone might provide is appreciated.
Thanks
Dominik